# Dynamic named lua objects

Tags: lua

Lets imagine this:

```
tree = {}
tree.__newindex = tree

num = math.random(5,5)

tree.meta = {}
```

What I want to do here is replace the 'meta' in tree.meta with the var num without it creating a new object just simply called num. That way I can do something like tree.01415 for example. Maybe there is some syntax that I can put in there to designate meta as the variable num?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you want:

```
tree[num] = "whatever"
```

Then `whatever` will be added to table `tree` with the value of `num` as its key.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to explain what I need to do is to ask the question: if you have say tree.meta, how could i call the class tree.meta.num with num as the variable. Is a dynamic call like this possible at all?

Comment: Sure, in that case you would use `tree.meta[num]`, which would retrieve the entry in table tree.meta with key num. The OOP-inspired dot notation is a shortcut for the square bracket notation, so `tree.meta.num` is the same as `tree.meta["num"]`. You need to use the square brackets to pass the contents of a variable instead of a string.

Comment: Ahh. Now it makes sense. I just couldn't wrap my head around that for some reason. Cheers!